# Flickering width animation in button

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, flicker

I'm beginner on CSS animation and have a problem.

This problems is a button animation, when on mouse over the button his infinitly flicker.

My css is

```
button {
        padding      : 0;
        width        : auto;
        border-radius: 0;
        background   : transparent;
        color        : $cinza;
        font-size    : 2.4rem;
        font-weight  : bold;
        transition   : color 0.2s linear, background-color 0.2s linear;

        &:hover {
          color           : $branco;
          background-color: $azul;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          padding-left: 0.5rem;
          border-radius   : 8px;

          span.titulo-botao {
            opacity: 1;
            width  : 150px;
          }
        }

        span.titulo-botao {
          display: none;
          opacity   : 0;
          width     : 0;
          transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
        }
      }
```

And my button:

```
<button title="Adicionar">
 <ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add"></ion-icon>
  <span class="titulo-botao">Adicionar</span>
</button>
```

The goal is on button hover the text with class ".titulo-botao" appears without flickering animation.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Dou you mean the flickering if the cursor is in the corner? If so, then move the `border-radius` to `button` instead of `:hover`

Comment: Solved this problem creating a div around span and set animation on div, but thanks